# Linking failure [ld cannot find library]

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

I am trying to configure Linux kernel [Angstrom distribution] via `make menuconfig`, but I get these errors.

```
make: Warning: File `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.61/arch/arm/Makefile' has modification time 11511 s in the future
make[1]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.host' has modification time 11393 s in the future
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

As far I know, ld cannot find library lgcc_s. How can i fix this? Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During kernel configuration, the linker is looking for `libgcc_s.so`. However, instead this file, there is `libgcc_s.so.1`. Linking succeeds by creating a link between the two files by running:

```
ln –s libgcc_s.so.1 libgcc_s.so
```